# JavaScript to use prevAll like jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

How to achieve this in JavaScript?

```
function prevAll (element) {
    // some code to take all siblings before element?
    return elements;
};
```

Comment: Get parent, loop all children, stop when you find the one you want (`element`). Come back when you have attempted something.. oh hang on, I think SLaks wants to do all your work for you. Just wait for his edit then you can get away without any effort at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `.previousElementSibling`, you get the previous node that's an actual element *(not a text node or comment)*.

```
function prevAll(element) {
    var result = [];

    while (element = element.previousElementSibling)
        result.push(element);
    return result;
}
```

The `.previousElementSibling` property can be polyfilled in IE8 if needed.

I should note that IIRC, jQuery returns the elements in document order. If that's the case and if that's what you need, just `.reverse()` the array when you return it.

Comment: @musefan: No, it'll only raise your  boss' expectations of you. ;-D

Comment: I doubt the OP will understand that last line: _"This can be polyfilled in IE8 if needed."_

Comment: @Cerbrus: Valuable keywords for research.

Comment: @squint: Ha! well played

Answer (score 0):

Use the `previousSibling` property, and loop until it's null.

Comment: Helping the OP without giving him the complete code? +1.

Comment: @Cerbrus: So... isn't that the same definition as an 'incomplete answer'?

Comment: Not necessarily. An explanation of _how_ it's done is often more educational than a block of code.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Because a loop is such an esoteric bit of knowledge... sure thing pal.

Comment: @squint: you'd be surprised. ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Nothing surprises me here. :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus: OP doesn't seem the type to be looking to learn stuff... rather just get stuff done

Comment: better to write at least logic

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator, if the situation called for it:

```js
const sibGen = function* (element) {
  let sibling = element.previousElementSibling; 
  while(sibling !== null) {
    sibling = sibling.previousElementSibling;
    yield sibling
  }
}
```

And then call it as:

```js
const siblingGenerator = sibGen(myElement);
// filter(Boolean) removes the null element
const allSiblings = [...siblingGenerator].filter(Boolean);
```