# Get all the previous elements in javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get all the previous elements of the element I clicked, just like .prevAll() does in jQuery.

I've read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207808/javascript-to-use-prevall-like-jquery) but I can't get it to work, I've just achieved that the prev one of what I clicked works.

Only the previous elements of divs inside .container-wrap

```js
const mejoras = document.querySelectorAll('.history:not(.first)');

mejoras.forEach(function(item){
      prev = item.previousElementSibling;

      function detach(node) {
        return node.parentElement.removeChild(node);
      }
      function insertAfter(newNode, existingNode) {
        existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
      }
  
    
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e){

      //Remove prev element
      detach(prev);
      //Put removed element after the one's clicked
      insertAfter(prev, item);

      item.classList.add('opened');
      item.style.width = '100%';

    })
  })
```

```html
<div class="container-wrap">
  <div class="history">1</div>
  <div class="history">2</div>
  <div class="history">3</div>
  <div class="history">4</div>
  <div class="history">5</div>

</div>
```

Comment: all previous elements in **ENTIRE DOCUMENT**? or just inside a specific element?

Comment: just inside a specific element @TheBombSquad